# There has to be a way to redirect everything to one page, right?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I have a site and I want to redirect everything to /index.html.

I'm replacing an old site so some visitors may try to access dead urls.  How can I do this through .htaccess?

Also, is there a way to rewrite the url in the process so they just see http://www.example.com and not whatever they originally tried to access?

Thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.html
```

the index.html shall stay in the same directory of the htacess

Comment: doesn't seem to work.  I get a 500 Internal Error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: It should work, it's a very standard code; you should check the path of the index.html page; can you post the directory structure?

Comment: My directory structure is just: /index.html, /img.jpg, /favicon.ico and /.htaccess.  I want someone who visits http://www.example.com/something to go to http://www.example.com

Comment: i edited the answer, did you checked again if it works?

Comment: yeah, thanks tried the latest.  It works for /something.html, but not /something

Comment: "something" should be the name of a page? or of a directory?

Comment: well the original site was drupal so "/something" would have been a page, not a real directory.  I added RewriteBase / and maybe its a coincidence, but /something.html and /something work, but /something/somethingelse doesn't - same deal with /something/ vs /something

Comment: Try "RewriteBase /something/" and then "Rewrite Rule .* something"

Comment: the problem with that is I don't know what the urls will be.  A visitor to the previous site could have bookmarked anything.  I just need it all to point to index.html.

Comment: redirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ index.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IIS.
2. Select your website in left pane.
3. In IIS 7 choose option `Default documents` in middle box and add your required index page. In IIS 3 right click on website in left pane and choose properties>home directory> then add your index page name and bring it to top (Top for priority).
4. In the same page you have option to redirect your URL to another URL

Comment: You do make the assumption that he is using IIS ...

Comment: OP used `.htaccess` tag -- most likely he uses Apache...

Comment: I am using Apache with .htaccess.